# Restoring Data from Subversion repository (Original data deleted)

Tags: svn, repository, restore

I guess, i couldnt find solution to this problem. The partition of my hard drive containing the source codes is corrupted, however I still do have one partition intact containing the SVN repository of that source code. Can anyone suggest me if I can retrieve whole data (my commited source code) from the repository alone?

Regards
Varun

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply checkout from your repository, and you'll get the complete source you last checked-in. Create a new directory, execute the following command:

```
$ svn checkout <repository url>
```

And you'll get a fresh new copy.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can get all of your source code back if the repository is intact. FIRST, BACK IT UP. Then, you should be able to do a checkout from the repository, and you will have your latest committed source code back.